# How to run the C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI) command in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On the [Frequently asked questions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp) page in the `How do I get IntelliSense to work correctly?` section it says that I can modify default settings by running the C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI) command.

How do I run the C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI) command in VSCode?

I can't find anything like that in VSCode menus and I can't find in Google how to run this command.

I tried typing the `C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)` command in the Terminal tab to run the command in VSCode but got *bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`* error.

Comment: try `Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Cmd+Shift+P`

Answer (score 2):

That command is for editing the config to the [C/C++ VSCode Extension by Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools). **You should install that first.** The extension does offer Intellisense support and some debbuging features for C and C++, but **does not** include a compiler. **To avoid weird errors, it's recommended that you install Clang or GCC prior to adding the extension.**

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to run it in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and not in the integrated terminal.